# Get all rows in a collection with only a specific property of object from Mongodb, I am using mongoose with that

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

[image]

I have the following collections in Database:
 - Exercises
 - Levels
 - Types

The collections have a name row which is an object and has values in three languages english, spanish and russian.

**I want to make a route like following:**

- /get/en/exercises : returns list of exercises with only english values of name. ("en" specified the language parameter)

Eg: `

```
[
        { _id: 324,
            name:{ en : "English name of exercise" },
            level:{ name: { en : "english name of level" }},
            type :{ name : { en : "English name of type" }}
        },
        { _id: 325,
            name:{ en : "English name of exercise" },
            level:{ name: { en : "english name of level" }},
            type :{ name : { en : "English name of type" }}
        },
        { _id: 326,
            name:{ en : "English name of exercise" },
            level:{ name: { en : "english name of level" }},
            type :{ name : { en : "English name of type" }}
        }
    ]
```

`

**If you think I am doing something wrong Please suggest me.
Please tell me how should I query my database for that?
**

Comment: First you should reconsider the architecture of your data. MongoDB is a noSql database, strong when it comes to huge data, weak when it comes to relations.

You could use of nested parameters.

    {
       _id,
       name,
       level_name,
       type_name,
    }

Comment: What if I have to do this with mongodb only. Can you suggest any query So I get the data in just one query.

Comment: So the answer is to use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) :)